# How to fix search locations in settings

Tags: settings, clock, auto-completion

After upgrade to 15.04, the auto-complete for location search in settings -> Time & Date stopped working:

[image]

Same problem with adding locations to the clock, however, I'm unable to take screenshot of that window with the problem.

Anyone else is experiencing the same? Any ideas how solve it?

Comment: Just to be clear, without auto-complete one can't search location or even worse, add location to the clock widget.

Comment: I also tried clean new user, no good.

Answer (score 1):

Is related to this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1440157

The workaround:

1. Downnload

   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libtimezonemap-data_0.4.4_all.deb
2. Download

   a) if 64bits:

   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libtimezonemap1_0.4.4_amd64.deb

   b) if 32bits:

   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libtimezonemap1_0.4.4_i386.deb
3. Install the two packages:

   a) 64bits

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libtimezonemap1_0.4.4_amd64.deb libtimezonemap-data_0.4.4_all.deb
   ```

   b)32bits

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libtimezonemap1_0.4.4_i386.deb libtimezonemap-data_0.4.4_all.deb
   ```